# Notification Widget in yosemite os

Tags: jquery, html, css, widget, dashcode

I want to create a notification widget (Using todays extension) which will have a dynamic layout.

Example my layout will be like a table with two rows and 3 column, which can change to a table with 3 rows and 5 column in the future.

Can we do this using HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

Please suggest a way to do so..

I don't wont to change the installable again, it will be given to user once and the layout can be changed dynamically...

I am using dashcode.

Comment: Please show your code effort.

Comment: Hi Maddy I don't have any code, as i have to research and figure out ways to add dynamically changing layout.Please suggest me the ways, like is there any way to add html file in today's extension ..